# Laravel save() is not update record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to update records in the database table if record already exists. Insert new record if record is not to the database table.

I have written below code for that

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
            $user->userCommission()->save(new UserCommission($input['commission']));
            dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

when EnableQueryLog it's always show insert query, If record is already in the table.

Here is my query..

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "insert into `user_commissions` (`created_by`, `status_id`, `percent`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:6 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "1"
      2 => "0.10"
      3 => 21
      4 => "2016-08-13 08:07:45"
      5 => "2016-08-13 08:07:45"
    ]
    "time" => 2.57
  ]
]
```

In above query user_id 21 record already in the table although `Save()` insert record to the database.

where am i wrong with this code?
May I have to apply unique key to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require at least one unique column to find or update table record

```
$userCommission = UserCommission::firstOrNew(array('created_by' => 1));
$userCommission->status_id = 1;
$user()->userCommission()->save($userCommission);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a alternative one way step to check this.update_at & created_at will be inserted by laravel default

```
userCommission::updateOrCreate([
                                'user_id' => 21
                                ],[
                                'created_by' => 1,
                                'status_id' => 1,
                                'percent' => "0.10",
                                'user_id' => 21,
                            ]);
```